# Libgdx OrthographicCamera zoom hidding part of Shaperenderer

Tags: android, camera, libgdx, viewport

I'm trying to make an isometric map on Android using libgdx. I'm basicaly drawing shapes with a ShapeRenderer and handling gestures by moving/zooming the camera. Here is my code.

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter{

    private OrthographicCamera cam;
    private ShapeRenderer mShapeRenderer;
    private InputHandler mInputHandler;


    @Override
    public void create() {
        mShapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
        mInputHandler = new AndroidInputHandler();
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(mInputHandler);
        Gdx.graphics.setContinuousRendering(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        System.out.println("render()");

        mInputHandler.handleInput(cam);
        cam.update();

        // clearing scene
        Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glClear( GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );


        //drawing updated scene
        mShapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

        mShapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
        mShapeRenderer.setColor( 0.95f, 0.95f, 0.95f,1);
        mShapeRenderer.rect(0, 0, 5.1f, 4.8f);
        mShapeRenderer.rect( 6.890f,24.014f,2.201f, 6f);
        mShapeRenderer.end();


    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        cam = new OrthographicCamera( 10f,10f * height / width);
        cam.position.set(5, 5, 7);
        cam.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
        Vector3 up =cam.position.cpy();
        up.nor();
        up.crs((new Vector3(-1, 1, 0)).nor());
        cam.up.set(up);
        cam.zoom=1f;
        cam.far=100000;
        cam.near=0;
    }

   ...
}
```

InputHandler is a custom class that handle gestures like pinch to zoom and camera translation. It only calls camera.translate(Vector3) and camera.zoom = new zoom.

My problem is that whenever i pinch to zoom, some of my shape are cut.

expected drawing

[image: Normal shapes]

cutted shapes

[image]

I don't realy know where this comes from. I think there is something happening with my viewport. I tried modifying the base zoom and camera viewport sizes but I dont realy understand the concept of viewport width and height.

Any help would be apreciated.

Thanks